# Cropping An Image (CIImage) To A UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, core-image

I have seen this question asked in varying ways on Stack Overflow, but I have not seen an implementation that leverages anything but UIKit to develop an approach.  For my use case, I have a `CIImage` and `UIBezierPath`  (rather, a set of points from a machine learning feature detection model) that I would like to use a "mask" for the CIImage.

For example, I may have an image of a person's face.  Subsequently, I may have a UIBezierPath that creates a closed shape around one of their eyes.  Ideally, I would like to "crop" my CIImage to encompass the UIBezierPath.  I recognize that since the final image will need to be square/rectangle, I would like to have any area outside of the UIBezierPath either black or transparent so it can be used as a mask for a future composition.

At present, I have code set up as such;

```
func doCrop(image: CIImage) -> CIImage {

  // The drawing context (here to show I need to use CIContext for another use later on in this function.
  let ciContext = CIContext()

  // The original source image
  let source = image

  // Setup the path
  let path = UIBezierPath()
  path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 0))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 600, y: 200))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 400))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200))
  path.close()

  // Test
  let cropped = source.cropped(to: path.bounds)

}
```

To be honest, I'm really unsure where to go from here. From what I have ascertained online, I see solutions that either implement UIKit to create an image context and draw a path, or solutions that only mask a UIImageView (which is not relevant for my needs, as I will need to draw this into a CIContext and pass through a Metal shader at a later point).

Comment: I'm likely missing something, but what's the issue? A `UIBezeirPath` by definition *is* a part of `UIKit`.Are you looking for something more... `CoreImage`?

Comment: That is correct, yes.  Sorry if that was unclear, but I am using wanting to avoid UIKit altogether if at all possible.  Given the image processing pipeline I have in place, UIKit would add too much overhead and I’d like to stick within CoreImage only.

Comment: Hey @ZbadhabitZ, I have the exact same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I'm confused by this code: you have function parameter `path` but you are shadowing it by creating a new one with `let path`, what's the role of the incoming `path` argument?

Comment: @johnbakers Fair question, I do see the confusion noted.  In this case, the defined `path` in the method's `let path = UIBezierPath()` line exists as an example of a potential path that could be provided to the function.  The redefined path in the method would not exist in real use case, and only the passed/incoming path would exist.